# Run external command from Python

Tags: python, bash, file-system, child-process

I have to run an external program from Python.  The external program makes many temporary files (which conflict with other instance of same program).

My strategy is:

1. get current directory (native) path
2. change to temp directory
3. run external command
4. copy output to native directory
5. change back to native directory

Here is my code:

```
import os, tempfile
current_dir = os.getcwd()
tmp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
input_file, outfile = 'input_file', 'result'
os.system('cp %s %s' %(input_file, tmp_dir)) 
os.chdir(tmp_dir)
cmd = 'pwd> tmp_01.txt;ls -ltr >>tmp_01.txt' ##system command goes here
os.system(cmd)
os.system('cp tmp_01.txt %s/%s' %(current_dir, outfile))
os.chdir(current_dir)
```

My questions are:

1. Is it right or is there a simpler way to do it?
2. Do I need to remove the tmp directory?
3. Is it safe to use this code as Python module/class in a web application? Does it make shell injection easy, or can it possible reveal more information than needed?

Comment: This code doesn't appear to do anything useful, so I've classified it as hypothetical / example code, which would be off-topic for Code Review.

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to shutil and subprocess.

To copy all the files:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile

```
import shutil
shutil.copy(src_file, destination_file)
```

To make the system calls:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call('ls -al', shell=True)
```

Comment: Please avoid shell and prefer using list arguments instead

Comment: Also, these are not system calls